# 500 error on function call in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using just installed CI 2.1.3
Following phpacademy tutorial I wrote in the routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
```

(instead of: $route['default_controller'] = "welcome";)

and in controllers/site.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Site extends CI_Controller {
      public function index() {
        echo "default function started.<br/>";

      }
      public function hello(){
        echo "hello function started.<br/>";
      }
}
```

After uploading it to the server and going to the [www.mydomain.ext] it works ok (writes: "default function started.") BUT if I add 'this->hello();' to the index() function it throws a 500 error.

Why does it happen and how can I resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well the most accurate way to find out what went wrong would be to inspect server log files if you have access to them. Although I find it hard to believe that a simple method call would be responsible for an error of that magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding `this->hello();` as you've mentioned above to your index function or `$this->hello();`?

`$this->hello();` should work fine (tested):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {
      public function index() 
      {
        echo "default function started.<br/>";
        $this->hello();
      }

      public function hello()
      {
        echo "hello function started.<br/>";
      }
}
```

Comment: It's embarrassing to be such a noob... Thank you, sbeliv :)